# Curl response hangs

Tags: networking, virtualbox, curl, nginx

I have a site set up in a virtual box. I am able to access it just fine from a browser on my machine, but I have trouble accessing it via CURL while SSH'ed in to the box.

When I try, curl hangs before displaying the response and exiting.

This is what I run: `curl -vvv site1.dev/`

This is the output it gives:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.10.10...
* Connected to site1.dev (192.168.10.10) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: site1.dev
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.9.7 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.9.7
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 16:47:30 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host site1.dev left intact
hi
```

The request portion is sent off right away, but the response hangs for a number of seconds (looks like 120ish), and then curl exits with that message: `* Connection #0 to host site1.dev left intact`

That is followed by the appropriate body of the response, "hi".

I'm a little lost -- any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit April 11:
I've tried wget and see a similar result (response hangs). I suspect it is a network config issue.

In case it is relevant, here is some of the port config for the virtual box.

```
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
```

EDIT April 12:

So... I decided to destroy this vagrant box and start fresh...doing this has resolved the problem.

I suspect that I changed/broke something over the course of the past several months. Starting over, with the vanilla box settings, has corrected that problem.

Comment: Do You have any active redirect in your `site1.dev`'s webserver?

Comment: You can try `curl -L site1.dev` to make curl follow redirects.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, that path resolves without redirects. It eventually does give the expected response...I just don't understand why it hangs before doing so...along with that "Connection #0..." message.

Comment: Given that the HTTP response shows that the server is sending the response body in chunks (see `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`), I am wondering if the server simply never sends the terminating chunk, and `curl` just "hangs", waiting for it...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps nginx is configured to do ip resolution of incoming requests and is taking time to resolve the incoming connection before actually answering the request.

A couple pointers though, you'll want to check the following on 192.168.10.10.

1. Verify name servers are correct within /etc/resolv.conf
2. If #1 resolv settings are are correct for primary and secondary nameservers, verify that 192.168.10.10 has the ability to resolve hosts. (simple nslookup to google.com is a good test for this, if timeout occurs then then this could be part of the issue)
3. Ensure that your nginx server has the ability to query name servers externally or internally via firewall (port 53 tcp/udp)
4. Look for potential resolver settings within nginx configuration options and or set resolution timeout setting where applicable and restart nginx.
5. If its still an issue attempt to add the host of the incoming request connection within /etc/hosts on 192.168.10.10.

Let me know how that works for ya..

Thanks for posting.

Comment: 1. Name server in resolv.conf is 10.0.2.3.
2. nslookup on google.com is fast and looks good.
3. Sorry, not sure how to do this. Recommendation?

Comment: If #2 is your nginx server then #3 should be fine.. Id check #4 next.

Answer (score 1):

Remark: You can get more detailed timing information by using `time curl -vvv site1.dev/`.

I note that the server reply contains `Connection: keep-alive`,
which means that the server is configured to use [HTTP keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) :

> HTTP persistent connection, also called HTTP keep-alive, or HTTP
>   connection reuse, is the idea of using a single TCP connection to send
>   and receive multiple HTTP requests/responses, as opposed to opening a
>   new connection for every single request/response pair. The newer
>   HTTP/2 protocol uses the same idea and takes it further to allow
>   multiple concurrent requests/responses to be multiplexed over a single
>   connection.

The server is therefore keeping the connection open in the expectation of
serving more requests. In this way, a browser can use the same TCP connection
to receive an HTML page and immediately request the linked images without
the need to establish new connections.

The [curl.1 man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) specifies the parameter `--no-keepalive` :

> Disables the use of keepalive messages on the TCP connection, as by
>   default curl enables them.

You may also parameter similarly the nginx server Module ngx_http_core_module
[keepalive_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout) :

> ```
> Syntax:   keepalive_timeout timeout [header_timeout];
> Default:  keepalive_timeout 75s;
> Context:  http, server, location
> ```
>
> The first parameter sets a timeout during which a keep-alive client
>   connection will stay open on the server side. The zero value disables
>   keep-alive client connections. The optional second parameter sets a
>   value in the “Keep-Alive: timeout=time” response header field. Two
>   parameters may differ.
>
> The “Keep-Alive: timeout=time” header field is recognized by Mozilla
>   and Konqueror. MSIE closes keep-alive connections by itself in about
>   60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Running curl with --no-keepalive gives the same results. Running the command with time provides the following info: - real 2m0.105s - user 0m0.008s - sys 0m0.004s.

Comment: Try also to disable keepalive in the server with keepalive_timeout=0.